# Spring 4 RMI server is not starting

Tags: spring, rmi

I am trying to integrate spring remoting with my existing spring beans but seems spring is not starting RMI server. I have done the neccessary configuration as described in the docs but seems it is doing nothing about RMI.Here are the logs when i run the main method.

> Jun 23, 2016 6:07:59 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@180bc464: startup date [Thu Jun 23 18:07:59 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jun 23, 2016 6:07:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [rmi-config.xml]

After this the Java process dies. I can't see anything related to RMI happening here.

Rmi-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd" default-lazy-init="true">


<bean id="validatorServiceBean" class="com.xyz.validator.service.impl.ValidatorServiceBean">
    <!-- any additional properties, maybe a DAO? -->
</bean>

 <!-- RMI Server Declaration -->
    <bean  class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">

        <!-- serviceName represents RMI Service Name -->
        <property name="serviceName" value="ValidatorServiceBean"/>

        <!-- service represents RMI Object(RMI Service Impl) -->
        <property name="service" ref="validatorServiceBean"/>

        <!-- serviceInterface represents RMI Service Interface exposed -->
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.xyz.validator.service.ValidatorService"/>

        <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
        <property name="registryPort" value="1009"/>

   </bean>


</beans>
```

My client code:

```
public class RMIServerStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        //RMI Server Application Context is started...
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rmi-config.xml");

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1009);

        for (String name : registry.list()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems XML entry doesn't have any impact when i used Java based configuration it started working.

```
 @Bean
 public RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter() {
  RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
  exporter.setServiceName("ValidatorService");
  exporter.setService(service);
  exporter.setServiceInterface(ValidatorService.class);
  exporter.setRegistryPort(1009);
  return exporter;
 }
```